# PromQL: how to change null value to an arbitrary value?

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

I have situation where my metric is set to 0 by a program when everything works fine. I would like to treat null value as an error value (in my case 1). The easiest approach I came up with is to replace null values in metric to 1. Grafana doesn't seem to support that, so my question is whether there is a PromQL expression to replace each null value with different one.

Comment: Probably, you need adding `or vector(1)` to the end of the query?

Comment: @valyala That doesn't really help if the query outputs multiple time series. It just adds a new time series with constant value of 1 over time (?)

Comment: Prometheus doesn't provide the ability to fill gaps with the given value for multiple time series. If you want this functionality in Prometheus-like system, then try `default` operator in [MetricsQL](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html). For example, `some_query default 1` fills gaps with 1 in all the time series returned by `some_query`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `null` in Prometheus, only samples that don't exist. It's easiest to always have your application expose a metric, however you can use `unless` on applications which don't do so. See [Absent Alerting for Scraped Metrics](https://www.robustperception.io/absent-alerting-for-scraped-metrics).